# Python program stops working if array of size greater than 1995 is passed to Array a

Tags: python, arraylist

I am trying to set an array of integer whose size is 10000.

However, Code works great if the length of the array `a` is less than 1995.
If I changed it to 2000 or more program stops working.

I want this code to work if I set array `a` of size 10000.
Here is the Python code:

```py
    import random
    random.seed()

    a = [random.randint(-1000, 1000) for i in range(10000)]
    DP = [[] for i in a]
    seq = []
    def solveDP(i):
        global DP
        if i >= len(a):
            return []
        if len(DP[i]) > 0:
            return DP[i]
        arr1 = [a[i]] + solveDP(i + 2)
        arr2 = solveDP(i + 1)
        if sum(arr1) > sum(arr2):
            DP[i] = arr1[:]    # Copy arr1 into DP[i]
        else:
            DP[i] = arr2[:]    # Copy arr2 into DP[i]
        return DP[i]

    print(solveDP(0))
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by stops working, does it throw an error? or do you no longer get the output that you desire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with the array length is with the recursive call of `solveDP`. I played around with your code and, at about 5980, I get the following error message:

> > Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\alexz\OneDrive\Programe\Python\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1.py",
> >     line 13, in solveDP
> >         arr1 = [a[i]] + solveDP(i + 2)   File "C:\Users\alexz\OneDrive\Programe\Python\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1.py",
> >     line 13, in solveDP
> >         arr1 = [a[i]] + solveDP(i + 2)   File "C:\Users\alexz\OneDrive\Programe\Python\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1.py",
> >     line 13, in solveDP
> >         arr1 = [a[i]] + solveDP(i + 2)   [Previous line repeated 995 more times]   File
> >     "C:\Users\alexz\OneDrive\Programe\Python\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1.py",
> >     line 7, in solveDP
> >         def solveDP(i):   File "e:\microsoft visual studio 2019\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd_vendored\pydevd_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_trace_dispatch_regular.py",
> >     line 343, in **call**
> >         is_stepping = pydev_step_cmd != -1 **RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison**

The bold line made me search for a bit and I found [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/what-is-the-maximum-recursion-depth-in-python-and-how-to-increase-it). According to the answer,

> It is a guard against a stack overflow, yes.

It looks to me that you call a function recursively so many times, that you filled the machine's stack.

Comment: Haven't tried it myself but this looks right. Python unfortunately doesn't support tail call optimisation so you'll have to find another implementation.

Comment: Thanks for replying. It will be very helpful if you provide me one sample code related to my code.

Comment: If all you want is to generate an array of 10000 random elements, I think recursion is an overkill